# Angular Material: Mat-Card restrict height for display

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have layout where on left side there is a `mat-table` - which is restricted in its height to 4 rows and on the right side a `mat-card`. The idea is to display the content of a selected row next to the table. Basically it should look like:

[image]

I put the two items in a grid layout. The problem I'm facing? If the `mat-card-content` is far too much it goes over the boundary  and looks quite nasty:

[image]

I tried to fix it but didn't succeed. How to fix it for this layout? If there is some kind math required for the CSS I would appreciate if the calculation can be tracked - since I need it little bit different in my project.

**UPDATE**: Forgotten the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wcpe6e?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.css) for the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just add this class and worked!

```
mat-card-content {
   overflow-y: scroll;
   max-height: 80px;
}
```

you can change max-height as much as you want.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wcpe6e-bjfyza?file=src/app/table-basic-example.css